# How to interpret error histogram and scatter plot?

Tags: regression, machine-learning, histogram

I'm new to machine learning and I'm having a hard time interpreting how good my model is performing. I have run my model on a dataset of [wine attributes](http://archive.ics.uci.edu/dataset/186/wine+quality) trying to predict alcohol content based on the other features. I noticed however that the loss looked very similar even when I started reducing the number of input features the model could use to make its predictions. Here is an extreme example where the model bases its predictions only on whether the wine is red or white (bottom row) compared to when the model has six other features to base it on (top row):
[image]
It is visiually obvious that these graphs look different, but I'm having a hard time understanding what the differences mean. How would I know, if I saw only the bottom row graphs, that something is off?

Comment: What makes you think the model on the bottom row is "off"?  Is it because you only have the top row with which to compare?

Comment: It's because I have trained it to make predictions based only on a boolean value. It should be much worse than if it had gotten multiple numerical values as well.